# BASH - parse PID from netstat using regex

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I've read loads of different people trying to do similar things (with tools like sed/awk/grep) and I've tried reading [docs](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) to build my own... But I'm failing to do what I perceived to be a relatively easy regex.

I'm parsing some netstat output, and I'm isolating the PID.

I'm aware that one connection can be used by multiple PIDs, but I also know that the specific types of connection I'm isolating will be single users on a particular service.

Minimum example of data I'm editing:

`users:((sshd,pid=1762,fd=5))`

I'm trying to isolate:

**pid=1762**

I was going to use (as an example) :

`echo "users:(("sshd",pid=1762,fd=5))"| sed "s/users:((//" | sed "s/))//"| cut -d "," -f2`

Which does exactly what I'm asking... But I just know that this is a bad solution. Could someone help me out a little please? :)

Comment: `echo 'users:((sshd,pid=1762,fd=5))' | sed 's/^.*sshd,//;s/,fd=.*$//'` or `echo 'users:((sshd,pid=1762,fd=5))' | awk -F, '{print $2}'`

Comment: Dude that awk field separator one is exactly the trick I was looking for! Thanks for the help :P

Comment: `your command that outputs | sed 's/.*\(pid=[0-9]*\).*$/\1/'`

Comment: Would you please try: `grep -oE "pid=[[:digit:]]+" <<< "users:((sshd,pid=1762,fd=5))"`

Answer (score 0):

[Jetchisel's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63211361/bash-grep-regex/63211483#comment111777278_63211361) suggested using awk's field separator option:

> `echo 'users:((sshd,pid=1762,fd=5))' | sed 's/^.*sshd,//;s/,fd=.*$//'` or `echo 'users:((sshd,pid=1762,fd=5))' | awk -F, '{print $2}'`

This worked perfectly.

Comment: you can also use `cut -d, -f2`

Answer (score 0):

For the above task, there is no need to run separate command to extract the pid component. You can use the bash built-in support for patterns, or regex. The advantage is that there is no need to run separate process - much faster if large number of input lines will be processed.

```
V='users:((sshd,pid=1762,fd=5))'

# Using Pattern
IFS=, read x1 x_pid x3 <<< "$V"
echo "$x_pid"
```

Or using REGEX

```
V='users:((sshd,pid=1762,fd=5))'

[[ "$V" =~ ,(pid=[0-9]+), ]] && x_pid=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
echo "$x_pid"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "users:((sshd,pid=1762,fd=5))" | cut -d',' -f2

echo "users:((sshd,pid=1762,fd=5))" | grep -o "pid=[0-9]*"
```

The latter appears to work as well, although I think -o is a GNU extension, so it may not be portable.